# Extracting XSD from an API

Tags: odata

I have the URL and credentials to call an Odata API which has as an operation a POST request to create an entity, however is it possible by having only this information somehow to retrieve the XSD for this entity?

I am also able to reach the {api_url}/$metadata document

Answer (score 0):

This isn't part of the OData standard. The OData standard defines the [Common Schema Definition Langauge](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-csdl-xml/v4.01/odata-csdl-xml-v4.01.html) (or what you see when you navigate to **{apiUrl}/$metadata**) as the schema langauge for OData endpoints.

So returning XSD as a schema/description language from an OData endpoint is not supported by any OData implementation because it's not part of the standard.

Also querying schema information for individual entities, was [talked about](https://www.odata.org/blog/queryable-odata-metadata/), but was never added. Basically what you get with **$metadata** is all you're gonna get for now.